# Can I still do port forwarding in order to make my local website public if I have two routers between me and the internet?

Tags: web-services, router, portforwarding

I am trying to host a website from my house. (It does not have to be very reliable and consistent, hence I'm hosting from my house from a Raspberry Pi).

My website is obviously working fine locally. I tried to configure port forwarding on my router. It did not work. I then realized that my IP address on https://www.whatismyip.com/ and my router IP address is not the same. After reading up I am suspecting that I am behind another router. That would make sense since I'm living in an estate/housing complex and one ISP provides internet to all units. I can't access the next router (probably due to security reasons from my ISP).

My question is, is there any way around this? Would an ISP in general perhaps grant me a port if I ask them?

P.s. I am using phpmyadmin with my website and I am using Java on a cron-job to execute a program every 2 minutes which changes the DB. So I am not sure website hosting on a third party site would be trivial in my case.

Answer (score 0):

it works now. I emailed my ISP to ask about the situation. Without further questions they assigned me a public IP address. I configured port forwarding and it works. Seems like you only get a public IP if you ask for one.